# Scripting language in qlikvew

Tags: scripting, qlikview

As far as I understand, the following is a comment in qlikview

```
 //This is a comment

'This is not a comment
```

Whats going on. I see a lot of VB script comments for qlikview on the net like
https://denvercoder9.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/qlikview-vb-scripting-for-newbies/

or here

http://community.qlik.com/thread/14503

Can some one please enlighten me? I simply created a qlikview file and pressed Ctrl + E to pull up the scripting window. Is there a default setting to set the language here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two types of scripts in QlikView: "Load" scripts and "Module" scripts.

A document's **Load Script** is executed when you perform a reload (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), and are responsible for obtaining your source data and transforming it so that you can use it in your QlikView document. Load script language is SQL-like in its appearance and uses C-style comments (`// Comment` or `/* multi-line comment */`), however as far as I can research there has been no official comment on what language it was originally based on.

You can edit this script using the script editor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

You find documentation on the syntax in the QlikView help installed with the application, or via the Reference manual which you can find here: http://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-4549

**Module Scripts** are methods that you can use to interact with the QlikView object model, for example, you can change font of objects (e.g. charts, buttons) or perhaps select values in List Boxes automatically. These are the type of scripts that you linked to in your question.

You may edit these scripts in the module editor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and they may be written in VBScript or JScript. If the script is written in VBScript, then any comments begin with a single quote, e.g. `' this is a comment`.

You can find documentation on the QlikView object model at http://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-2640.

Comment: Thanks Drones, finally dawned upon me.

Answer (score 3):

The Load language is pretty similar to VB, however it is based on the Lua Language as you can see in: http://documentation.qlikview.com/expressor/3.8/expressor_datascript_language/datascript_language_reference_guide/The_Datascript_language.htm

Comment: Hi Jclozano, But why do I see so many VBScripts floating around for qlikview? Are they supposed to be used on the script(Ctrl+E) or some where else.

Comment: As you can see on i_saw_drones answer, that is the module functionality, where you can code on VBScript